# Behavior of TimelinePlot with multiple datasets of associations

Tags: plotting, bugs, date-and-time, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.1 and fixed in 10.3**

---

The following `TimelinePlot` behaves as I would expect:

```
TimelinePlot[{
   <|"key1" -> Interval[{{2010, 1, 1}, {2011, 1, 1}}],"key2" -> {2012, 4, 1}|>, 
   <|"key1" -> Interval[{{2010, 3, 1}, {2011, 1, 1}}],"key2" -> {2012, 1, 2}|>}]
```

[image]

However, if the keys of the second association are changed, the plot does not work:

```
TimelinePlot[{
   <|"key1" -> Interval[{{2010, 1, 1}, {2011, 1, 1}}],"key2" -> {2012, 4, 1}|>, 
   <|"hello" -> Interval[{{2010, 3, 1}, {2011, 1, 1}}],"goodbye" -> {2012, 1, 2}|>}]
```

[image]

Are datasets required to have the same keys?  That seems like a peculiar requirement.

Comment: That's interesting; I'll report it. As a workaround, you can change this to using `Labeled`, instead: `TimelinePlot[Map[KeyValueMap[Labeled[#2, #1] &, #] & @ data]`.

Comment: So should this be tagged as a bug?

Comment: I find the documentation a bit ambiguous here. The wording wrt the third syntax and Associations could perhaps be interpreted to say that the whole argument should be contained in a single Association containing all events. All examples with associations that I have seen do this (no curly braces), so the syntax you're using might not be intended.

Comment: This bug appears to be fixed in MMA 10.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed in version 10.3.

[image]