# TimelinePlot with Interval in Associations

Tags: bugs, date-and-time, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.2 and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

This is related to a previous question I asked about `TimelinePlot` and multiple associations ([Behavior of TimelinePlot with multiple datasets of associations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79039/behavior-of-timelineplot-with-multiple-datasets-of-associations)), but in that case a single association was functioning properly (under v10.1). Under v10.2, it appears that even a single association will not work with `TimelinePlot`.  Specifically, the example in the documentation:

```
TimelinePlot[<|"key1" -> Interval[{{2010, 1, 1}, {2011, 1, 1}}],"key2" -> {2012, 1, 2}|>]
```

yields a long list of errors (too long to post here, unless someone feels strongly about it).

This happens for me with v10.2 on a MacBook Air running OS X 10.9.5. Can anyone else confirm it on another platform?

Comment: This is a confirmed bug. It only happens with a specific date form, inside of `Interval`, inside of an `Association`. Unfortunately, date list is a popular date form. Use `DateObject`, instead.

Comment: This bug appears to be fixed in 10.3.